# Search for files that contain 2 or more occurrences of a specific word between text with new lines

Tags: string, bash, search, grep

I need to search for files that contain 2 or more occurrences of a specific word (in my case `NORMAL`), so from files like the following:

**file1.txt**:

```
the NORMAL things are [

    - case
    - case 2
    
    a NORMAL is like [

        - case 3
        - case 4
        
    ]
    
]
```

**file2.txt**:

```
the NORMAL things are [

    - case
    - case 2
    
    a DIFFERENT is like [

        - case 3
        - case 4
        
    ]
    
]
```

**file3.txt**:

```
the NORMAL things are [

    - case
    - case 2
    
]
```

it will find **file1.txt** only.

I have tried with a simple `grep`:

```
grep -Ri "*NORMAL*NORMAL*" .
```

but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Title is contradictive to your description, regarding the pattern you search. Is it just `NORMAL` or any line with `NORMAL` only if next and previous lines are empty or have only white-space characters ot are file bountaries.

Comment: Does NORMAL match when it occurs in `FOONORMALBAR`? What if the rtsing you wanted to find was `foo.bar` instead of `NORMAL` - would `foo.bar` match against `fooXbar` or not? Just trying to find out if you need full or partial matching and regexp or string matching. I'd think you'd want full word string matching but most every answer so far is using partial matching and only 1 of them is using string matching, the rest are using regexp matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not wish to  search recursively:

```
grep -lzE '(NORMAL).*\1' files*
```

If you do wish to search recursively:

```
grep -rlzE '(NORMAL).*\1' .
```

This command is checking recursively in the current directory, for the file which contains `NORMAL` followed by `NORMAL`(`\1`) in the file. Meaning it will match 2 or more matches.  This is only printing filename, remove `-l` to print the content + filename.

`-l` : This would only print the file name if matched by `grep`
`-z`:  a data line ends in 0 byte, not a newline
`-E`: use  extended regular expression
`-r`: recursive

Answer (score 0):

Use [`grep -c`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) to print counts of matches:

```
grep -c 'PATTERN' file(s)
```

In you case, you also need a second `grep -Pv` or something similar to filter by the number of matches (here, exclude files with 0 or 1 matches):

```
grep -c 'NORMAL' files | grep -P -v ':[01]$'
```

Here,
`:[01]` : `:` followed by either 0 or 1 (selects 0 or 1 matches).
`$` : end of the line.

**SEE ALSO:**

> -c
> --count
> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file. With the -v (--invert-match) option, count
> non-matching lines. (-c is specified by POSIX.)
>
> -P
> --perl-regexp
> Interpret patterns as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).
>
> -v
> --invert-match
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX.)

(from [GNU Grep 3.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html))

Answer (score 0):

> fgrep -c 'NORMAL' file* | awk -F ":" ' $NF >= 2 { print }'

file1.txt:2

If you want to print search results as well then

> fgrep -c 'NORMAL' file* | awk -F ":" ' $NF >= 2 { print }' | grep NORMAL $(awk -F ":" '{ print $1}')

the NORMAL things are [

a NORMAL is like [

Answer (score 0):

Use grep -o option:

Ex:

```
grep -o NORMAL file1.txt | wc -l --> 2
grep -o NORMAL file2.txt | wc -l --> 1
grep -o NORMAL file3.txt | wc -l --> 1
```

Now this can be used with if claus:

```
if [ `grep -o NORMAL file1.txt | wc -l` -ge 2 ];then echo "Count is greater than or equal to 2";else echo "Count is less than 2";fi
```